# websocket connection keeps disconnecting [Android]

Tags: android, service, websocket, android-service

My app makes a websocket connection to a URL using [this library](https://github.com/codebutler/android-websockets). Everything is working fine. The app is a communication app (sends and receives messages). When the app goes to the background (pressing the home key) the websocket connection still works and the user receives push notifications for new messages.

The problem is that, when the app is in background, after some amount of time, the websocket connection disconnects automatically. Now this time interval is different each time (sometimes 5 seconds, sometimes 5 minutes).

Now the problem is not with the URL (no idle time/timeout issues - believe me, it works fine on other platforms). So I am looking for possible reasons for this behaviour so I can fix the problem.

How could the websocket connection be disconnected when the app goes in the background. Also, should I run a continuous background service as a remedy?

PS: There is no service in the app right now. The library is supposed to let the websocket connection running when the app goes to the background.

Comment: *should I run a continuous background service as a remedy?* so the code is in Activity? Why? It is stated in android application fundamentals which app component is what for ... also did you aquire any locks? or allow the cpu to get truned off?

Comment: I am not doing anything of that sort. The library is supposed to enable the websocket connection to run when the app goes to background.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the library you are using does not *stop* the connection when the app is backgrounded... however, Android may kill the process.

A `Service` exists specifically to prevent that problem. If you implement it in a `Service` it should solve your problem.

A word of caution: just because you *can* do this it does not mean that you *should* do this. Be careful about memory and battery usage when you implement a `Service`. They are intended to run in the background indefinitely - and you can make some users very unhappy if you have CPU/battery intensive code, or Android may kill the `Service` if it consumes too much memory.